# Фатальная ошибка при вызове fetch()

Tags: php, ооп, mvc, запрос, pdo

Пытаюсь сделать вывод из базы данных,подключаюсь к ней с помощью PDO,вывод пытаюсь сделать через цикл `while`, и при вызове функции `fetch()` выдает ошибку:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on boolean in
>   /home/s/ser588nn/shop.ser588nn.beget.tech/public_html/models/News.php
>   on line 24

Скорее всего при выполнении запроса, `query` возвращает `false`,хотя запрос проверял все верно.

Модель :

```
        public static function getNewsList()
        {
            //Запрос к БД
            $host = '127.0.0.1';
            $dbname = 'ser588nn_shop';
            $user = 'ser588nn_shop';
            $password = 'rootroot';
            $db = new PDO("mysql:host = $host;dbname = $dbname",$user, $password);

            $newsList = array();

                $result = $db->query('SELECT id, title, date, short_content FROM news ORDER BY date LIMIT 10');



        $i = 0;
        while($row = $result->fetch()) {
            $newsList[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
            $newsList[$i]['title'] = $row['title'];
            $newsList[$i]['date'] = $row['date'];
            $newsList[$i]['short_content'] = $row['short_content'];
            $i++;
        }
        return $newsList;   
}

}
?>
```

Контроллер:

```
<?php

include_once ROOT. '/models/News.php';


class NewsController {
    public function actionIndex()
        {

            $newsList = array();
            $newsList = News::getNewsList();

            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($newsList);
            echo "</pre>";
            return true;
        }

    public function actionView($id)
    {
        echo "Список одной новости";
        return true;
    }


}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ПДО - это не тупая mysql_query, тут не нужно вручную колупаться, чтобы получить массив.

```
public static function getNewsList()
{
    $sql = "SELECT id, title, date, short_content FROM news ORDER BY date LIMIT 10";
    return Db::getConnection()->query($sql)->fetchAll();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо,ваш ответ намного лучше,оказывается можно было реализовать это в 2 строчки.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static function getNewsList()
    {
        //Запрос к БД
        $host = '127.0.0.1';
        $dbname = 'ser588nn_shop';
        $user = 'ser588nn_shop';
        $password = 'rootroot';
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host = $host;dbname = $dbname",$user, $password);

        $newsList = array();


        $result = $db->prepare('SELECT id, title, date, short_content FROM news ORDER BY date LIMIT 10');
        $result -> execute();

        $row = $result -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $newsList['id'] = $row['id'];
        $newsList['title'] = $row['title'];
        $newsList['date'] = $row['date'];
        $newsList['short_content'] = $row['short_content'];

        return $newsList; 

    }
```

Comment: А как сделать ,чтобы значения в массиве выводились тоже?

Comment: А то щас результат такой   Array
(
    [id] => 
    [title] => 
    [date] => 
    [short_content] => 
    [short_content1] => 
)

Comment: Дай скриншот вывода

Comment: @СергейСамохвалов, не нужно пытаться вставить скриншот в ответ, добавьте в комментарий.

Comment: Какое-то жульничество. Почему этот бредовый ответ признан правильным?

Comment: Вы правы,ваш ответ более правильный.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static function getNewsList()
    {
        //Запрос к БД

        $db = Db::getConnection();
        $newsList = array();


        $result = $db->query("SELECT id, title, date, short_content FROM news");

        $i = 0;
        while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
            $newsList[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
            $newsList[$i]['title'] = $row['title'];
            $newsList[$i]['date'] = $row['date'];
            $newsList[$i]['short_content'] = $row['short_content'];
            $i++;
        } 
        return $newsList;
}
}
?>
```